# MySQL Query to list users who have recently messaged

Tags: mysql, sql, psql

I'm building a chat application and I want to list the users who have recently messaged, with their `id, name, pic, and last message (id, timestamp, content)`

My two tables look like this:

```
users:
------
id
name
pic

messages:
---------
id
content
timestamp
user_id (foreign key of user's id)
```

Here is the query that I've tried:

```
SELECT U.*, 
    MAX(M.id) as lastmessage_id 
FROM users U, messages M 
WHERE M.user_id=U.id 
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY lastmessage_id DESC
```

It will list the users who have messaged recently but it doesn't contain the last message's 'content'

Current output:

```
id, name, pic, lastmessage_id
```

Required output:

```
id, name, pic, lastmessage_id, lastmessage_content, lastmessage_timestamp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find all the latest message id for each user and then join it with messages table to get the corresponding rows:

```
select u.*,
    m.*
from users u
join messages m on u.id = m.user_id
join (
    select user_id,
        max(id) as id
    from messages
    group by user_id
    ) t on m.id = t.id
        and m.user_id = t.user_id
order by m.id desc;
```

Also, always use explicit modern join syntax instead of old comma based syntax.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Your query is much faster than @mosheb

Answer (score 1):

In your script, you display all the columns in users table, but just id from messages table. Change your script to below one.

```
SELECT U.*, 
    MAX(M.id) as lastmessage_id , M.content, M.timestamp
FROM users U, messages M 
WHERE M.user_id=U.id 
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY lastmessage_id DESC
```

Comment: It won't work. I've tried before
#1055 - Expression #12 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'messengerify.M.content' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM users U, messages M
WHERE M.user_id=U.id
 and M.id=(select max(M2.id)
    from messages M2
    where M2.user_id = U.id)
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. However @Gurwinder Singh posted the answer little more faster and his query is very fast

Comment: i posted this mainly due to my preference for this style of sql which I feel is very clean and clear

Comment: Yup. I got it. It's clean and short

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
select t1.id,t1.name,t1.pic,t1.lastmessage_id from (SELECT U.id,U.name,U.pic,(M.id) as lastmessage_id FROM users U, messages M WHERE M.user_id=U.id ORDER BY lastmessage_id DESC) t1
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a JOIN:

```
SELECT U.*, MAX(M.id) AS lastmessage_id 
FROM users U

JOIN MESSAGES M ON U.id = M.user_id

GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY lastmessage_id DESC
```

Comment: it doesn't contain 'content' column from messages